# JSON - Is it possible that in an array, some of the objects don´t have all fields?

Tags: arrays, json

For example:

```
    {
        "name":"CarShop",
        "city": "Xixon",
        "cars": [
            { "name":"Ford", "amount": 5, "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus" ]},
            { "name":"Seat", "amount": 4, "models":[ "Ibiza", "Cordoba"]},
            { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
            { "name":"Fiat", "amount": 10 }
        ]
     }
```

We can see that the last two obejcts are missing a field, one "amount" and the other one "models". Is is a valid JSON?

Comment: Yes, it is valid.

Comment: @Ryan, that was a mistake of me while writting the example. I forgot a comma. My point was, and you both already replied yes, if the structure of the objects in an array can be different, missing or including new fields.

Comment: I am not executing anything. I just wanted to know if the situation was possible. The script is just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` is not a `valid JSON` not because of missing property from last two objects in an array it is because `JSON` is not formatted correctly.

**Invalid JSON :**

[image]

**Valid JSON :**

[image]

Yes, it is possible you can put any number of properties in an objects.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj =     {
        "name":"CarShop",
        "city": "Xixon",
        "cars": [
            { "name":"Ford", "amount": 5, "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus" ]},
            { "name":"Seat", "amount": 4, "models":[ "Ibiza", "Cordoba"]},
            { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
            { "name":"Fiat", "amount": 10 }
        ]
     };
     
for (var i in jsonObj.cars) {
  console.log(jsonObj.cars[i].amount);
}
```

Comment: I eddited it, I forgot a comma when I was typing that example. The question was about the number of fields in each aray object, if it is possible or not.

Comment: Is it possible. you can put any number of properties in an objects. The only thing is while iterating the object you have to take care of the properties.